# VK_KHR_acceleration_structure and VK_KHR_raytracing_pipeline aren't presented whereas they are available in vkconfig (RTX2060)

Tags: vulkan, raytracing, hardware-acceleration, rtx

I want to use VK_KHR_acceleration_structure and VK_KHR_raytracing_pipeline VkDevice extensions in my project. The problem is that vkPhysicalDeviceExtensionProperties has no those extensions whereas they are presented by vulkaninfo in vkconfig. In addition to it accelerationStructure flag from VkPhysicalDeviceAccelerationStructureFeaturesKHR structure is enabled, same with rayTracingPipeline flag from VkPhysicalDeviceRayTracingPipelineFeaturesKHR. I have only one VkPhysicalDevice available, so I don't know any reasons for it.

An actual error occures when I'm trying to create VkDevice with these extensions.

My setup:

- System - Windows 10,
- Vulkan SDK - 1.3.250.1, Volk extensions functionality, API version - 1.3
- Video card - RTX2060 with DCH 536.67 version drivers.

I tried to use required functionality without these extensions, use another API version (from 1.1 to 1.3), reinstall Vulkan SDK, update drivers, use VulkanAPI functions only (no Volk, loading functions by vkGetInstanceProcAddr).

Comment: The database RTX2060 does not have these extensions:https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=22764#extensions, I remember ray tracing is introduce from 30XX cards.

Comment: But they are in list you send.

Comment: "*In addition to it accelerationStructure flag from VkPhysicalDeviceAccelerationStructureFeaturesKHR structure is enabled*" Is that something vkConfig is telling you or is your application seeing that? Also, what layers do you have active?

Comment: I got this info from vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2 function with this structure in pNext chain, so yes, I got this info from application.

Comment: I'm using VK_LAYER_RENDERDOC_Capture and VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation layers

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in VK_LAYER_RENDERDOC_Capture layer, that blocked bunch of extensions.